# VBA Userform textbox default value and highlighted

Tags: excel, vba, textbox, userform

In my UserForm, I want to set a default value for my TextBox, that will highlight when focused upon.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

NameTextBox.Value = "Your Name Here"

NameTextBox.SetFocus

End Sub
```

When this code runs, the cursor should set at the end of the default text, i.e. after "...Here". I want "Your Name Here" to be highlighted so that when the form is generated, the user can start replacing that default/placeholder text.

Can you help me write the code to set default values that are editable?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This will select all the text in the TextBox:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
With Me.NameTextBox
    .Value = "Your Name Here"
    .SetFocus
    .SelStart = 0
    .SelLength = Len(.Text)
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the `EnterFieldBehavior` property to `frmEnterFieldBehaviorSelectAll` so that when the focus goes to that field, the whole field is selected.

Answer (score 0):

in newer versions of excel, Right Click the form in an empty space (in form designer) and click on "Tab order" then there you can set your order correctly for which fields you want to be selected on form launch first.

Answer (score -4):

how about this line of code when your form loads?

```
NameTextBox.SelectAll()
```

Comment: When I add that bit of code as the last line I get a `Compile Error: Expected: =`

Comment: bfs1990 said what the error is. To be more specific a Userform Textbox has no "SelectAll" method. I downvoted this answer.

Comment: ah sorry for the confusion. I assumed that the text box used was in the System.Windows.Forms namespace.

[link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox(v=vs.110).aspx)